# How do I install GLIBC in Kali/Debian?

Tags: debian, kali-linux, glibc

How can I install GLIBC? When I installed Spotify on my Kali 1.0.9a it gives me the following output when I try running Spotify through the Terminal:

```
spotify: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found 
(required by spotify)
spotify: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/libcef.so)
spotify: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/spotify/spotify-client/Data/libcef.so)
```

Comment: FFS. Kali Linux is a penetration testing distro, not one designed for desktop use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found), 
The problem is that the program was compiled against 2.14 and you've got an older version. 
My suggestion is that you compile a new version of Libc.